# How to setup autoload for Laravel 4 package

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a new Laravel 4 app and am trying to add the [laravel-oauth2](https://github.com/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2) vendor package.

I ran

```
composer require taylorotwell/laravel-oauth2
composer dump-autoload
```

successfully. But I get `Class 'OAuth2' not found`

Advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method of adding packages to the Laravel 4 framework would be:

1. add a line to the "require" section of the main composer.json file, e.g.
   "taylorotwell/laravel-oauth2": "0.2.*"
2. run "composer update"

This will download the package and refresh the autoload classes. I just did a test and  it seems to work ok, remember to use the namespace:

```
$provider = \OAuth2\OAuth2::provider('facebook', array(
    'id' =>     'client id',
    'secret' => 'client secret',
));
```

or

```
use OAuth2\OAuth2;

$provider = OAuth2::provider('facebook', array(
    'id' =>     'client id',
    'secret' => 'client secret',
));
```

Comment: Thanks Kemal.. sorry about that :/

Comment: The use statement is just what the package docs were missing.